# Non-vanishing of Dirichlet $L$-function $L(s,\chi)$ for $\Re(s)=1$

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory, analytic-number-theory, dirichlet-series, l-functions

I know that if $\chi$ is a non-principal Dirichlet character then the $L$-function $L(s,\chi)$ doesn't vanish for $s=1$. But, how about $s=1+it$ with $t\neq 0$? I found in this post: [Zeros of Dirichlet L-functions on the line R(s)=1 in proof of Dirichlet's theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1346880/zeros-of-dirichlet-l-functions-on-the-line-res-1-in-proof-of-dirichlets-th) that indeed, $L$-functions never vanish. Where can I find a proof of it? I've looked in some books and googled it, but couldn't find anything. Can sombody provide a reference? Thank you very much!

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2505472/11323

Comment: Thank you, this was what I was looking for!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Non-vanishing of Dirichlet $L$ function $L(s,\chi)$ for $Re s=1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2505472/non-vanishing-of-dirichlet-l-function-ls-chi-for-re-s-1)

Comment: yeah for sure! thanks!